# Unity のAndroid Build から x86 対応端末リストを除外する方法

Tags: android, unity3d, google-play

Androidアプリのリリースで、x86端末はテスト不十分なことから除外したいのですが、
UnityのPlayerSetting > DeviceFilter で ARMv7 のみを指定しても、
GooglePlayにApkをアップすると、
ネイティブ プラットフォーム armeabi-v7a, x86 となってしまい
対応端末に x86機種が並んでしまいます。

さすがに、手動でリストから削除するのは
これからの新機種にも目を光らせないといけないので
現実的ではないように思えますが、
何か対応方法をご存知のかたよろしくお願いします。